# Calendar database schema issue with HTC Desire HD

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

Calendar application(Android) database stores meeting body data usually in "description" column of Events table (as what i have tested on major manufacturers devices including HTC, Samsung, LG, Sony Ericsson) but HTC DesireHD always returns null for this column.

Uri for Events table is as following

content://com.android.calendar/events.

When i am getting the cursor, it gives me null for description column for each record though i can see the body text in for the corresponding meeting in the calendar view.

I doubt that there is a serious bug with the database schema in htc desire HD, they must be storing the meeting note somewhere but not in the usual column (which is description of Events table). Please help in getting my doubts rights?

any help is highly appreciable...